# Launch app using IOS share extension

Tags: objective-c, ios8, ios-extensions

I am using IOS8 share extension, what needed here is to launch your app when user select post from safari in app extension.

I tried using `openURL` for this but, `[UIApplication sharedapplication]` doesn't works in extensions.

Comment: Do you have an example of some code that you've already tried?

Comment: This doesn't work. Share extensions are not meant to start your App. You have to implement the sharing you want to provide in the share extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No,you cant open any application through share extension, while you can do this with today extension.

Comment: is it possible in Action Extension?